# How to detect element and cut into group in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with HTML tables and need to achieve color change in a certain way. 
My desired result is as described below.

Lower figure shows that assume current state is upper figure,then cell `1` is clicked,upper figure becomes like lower figure.

[image]

I would like to select`first`element,and then add 'aqua' class after`5`cells including first cell.

I achieved to select `first` cells among these clicked cells,But I couldn't figure out how to detect after 5 cells which has 'class'.

If someone has opinion,please let me know

Thanks

```js
$("td").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("red");
  $("td.aqua").removeClass("aqua");
  $("td.red").first().addClass("aqua");
  
});
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.red {
background-color:red;}

.aqua{
background-color:aqua;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>

<script>
let html = ''
html += '<table>';
let i = 0;


for (let w = 0; w < 5; w++) {
  html += '<tr>';
  for (let d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
    i=i+1;
    html += '<td>'+ i+'</td>'
    }
    html += '</tr>';
  }
html += '</table>'
document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand correctly what you need to do, but this will color the clicked cell in aqua and the following 5 cells in red. Even if it's not exactly what you need, it should guide you in the right direction.

```
$('body').on('click', "td", function() {
  let _this = this;
  let _index = -1;
  $(this).parents('table').find('td').each(function(i, el){
    if(el == _this){
      _index = i;
    }
    if (_index > -1 && i > _index && i < (_index + 6)){
      console.log(i);
      $(el).addClass('red');
    }
  });
  $(this).addClass("aqua");
});
```

On a logical level you need to loop through all your `td` elements and detect which one of them has been clicked, get the index if it and then add the class `red` to the following 5 elements. Apply class `aqua` to the clicked one either at the end or at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Does this what you want?

```js
$("table").on("click", "td", function(ev) {
  $(this).removeClass("aqua").addClass("red");

  let nextRowIdx = this.parentNode.rowIndex,
      nextCellIdx = this.cellIndex + 5;
  if (nextCellIdx >=10) {
    nextRowIdx += 1;
    nextCellIdx -= 10;
  }
  try {
    let tbl = this.parentNode.parentNode,
        cell = tbl.children[nextRowIdx].children[nextCellIdx];
    $(cell).removeClass("red").addClass("aqua");
  } catch (err) {
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.red {
background-color:red;}

.aqua{
background-color:aqua;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>

<script>
let html = ''
html += '<table>';
let i = 0;


for (let w = 0; w < 5; w++) {
  html += '<tr>';
  for (let d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
    i=i+1;
    html += '<td>'+ i+'</td>'
    }
    html += '</tr>';
  }
html += '</table>'
document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;

</script>
```